# SQL Server Reporting Services - http 403 forbidden - website declined to show this webpage

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Reporting Services was working fine until recently, now when I try to deploy and run a report from Business Intelligence Studio I get this error.

Similarly when I try to connect to the ReportServer URL directoy from IE Explorer, (set to http:///ReportServer  I get the same error, so it's not specific to the report but probably rather to the ReportServer or IIS configuration.

I went through all the Properties of the website, comparing to another website on the same machine, and it seems identical.

Any ideas on what's wrong or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you recently change the password of the account the service is running under?  Can you give the real error message and not the friendly error message?  In other words, use a browser besides IE that tells you the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

SSL problem?  Has your cert expired?  You say http, but not sure if you're using ssl.

Also, just to be sure, the URL should be http://SERVER/ReportServer.