# The website declined to show this webpage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I get this error

```
The website declined to show this webpage
```

on my webserver when visiting 
http://localhost/exampledomain.com/

I enabled failed request tracing rules for `ASP`, `ASP.NET`, `ISAPI Extention` and `WWW Server` for `403 status codes` but no log files are created at `C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles`

Is this a firewall issue or something?

Comment: If it was a firewall issue then it wouldn't get as far as "The website declined to show this webpage". It sounds more like you haven't configured IIS correctly, or your Application Pool doesn't have permissions to the directory of where the application is located.

Comment: What a waste of points. There are several mentions by Google so that you should at least have been able to provide more information and make it a good question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your question lack a lot of information. But a [quick search on Google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=The%20website%20declined%20to%20show%20this%20webpage%20iis&oq=The%20website%20declined%20to%20show%20this%20webpage%20iis&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i19k1j0i22i30i19k1l3.4428.5257.0.5627.4.4.0.0.0.0.109.371.3j1.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.368...0j0i22i30k1.WIbXeUJXLN8) reveals a lot of links with a possible
 solutions.

- https://forums.iis.net/t/1214595.aspx?403+The+website+declined+to+show+this+webpage
- https://forums.asp.net/t/1640590.aspx?Web+Hosting+in+IIS+Error+HPPT+403+Forbidden+The+website+declined+to+show+this+webpage
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/9f18f483-3e3f-4591-b028-9f8c4e1efb10/website-declined-to-show-this-webpage?forum=sharepointadminlegacy
- https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24446761/The-website-declined-to-show-this-webpage-IIS6-Web-Service.html
- https://rehmangul.wordpress.com/2009/04/09/error-the-website-declined-to-show-this-web-pagethe-website-requires-you-to-log-in/
- http://www.kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/48462

Or a list with links found [on StackOverflow](https://www.google.nl/search?q=The%20website%20declined%20to%20show%20this%20webpage%20iis%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=The%20website%20declined%20to%20show%20this%20webpage%20iis%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2439.2439.0.2627.1.1.0.0.0.0.60.60.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.euHPwlRkIJM) alone, which could have some useful information.

- [IIS7 403 - Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369921/iis7-403-access-denied)
- [Why do i get this error: "The website declined to show this webpage"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035903/why-do-i-get-this-error-the-website-declined-to-show-this-webpage)
- [IIS 7.5 - 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111911/iis-7-5-403-forbidden)
- [IIS 7.0 Deployment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500779/iis-7-0-deployment-issue)
- [SQL Server Reporting Services - http 403 forbidden - website declined to show this webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469077/sql-server-reporting-services-http-403-forbidden-website-declined-to-show-th?rq=1)

But the most common causes for this error seem to be the issues mentioned below. Most links mention one or more of these as a possible solution.

- Incorrect framework version
- Early exception in your Application_Start
- Incorrect MVC version installed
- Permission error on files/folders or AppPool
- Framework not correctly registered > run `aspnet_regiis -ir`